# property .count returns all xml nodes in xpath

Tags: c#, xpath

I am trying to filter out one xml document using xpath and count number of nodes which contain given string.
here is my code

```
    string ElementValue = Action
    nodeList = root.SelectNodes(@"/moviedb/movie[contains(genres, "+ ElementValue +")]");
                return nodeList.Count;
```

and part of XML

```
    <moviedb>
<movie>
    <imdbid>tt2226321</imdbid>
    <genres>Thriller</genres>
    <languages>English</languages>
    <country>USA</country>
    <rating>8</rating>
    <runtime>155</runtime>
    <title>The Dark Knight</title>
    <year>2014</year>
  </movie>
  <movie>
    <imdbid>tt1959490</imdbid>
    <genres>Action,Adventure,Drama</genres>
    <languages>English</languages>                                        
    <country>USA</country>
    <rating>6.5</rating>
    <runtime>138</runtime>
    <title>Noah</title>
    <year>2014</year>
  </movie>
</moviedb>
```

I guess that it is something with xpath contains expression. While i was using full match syntax, everything was working correctly.

thanks again

Comment: Check out your previous question and compare resulting XPath between questions... Hint: Quotes... double quotes... single quotes.... To make this question answerable make sure to add line `string ElementValue = {real value here}` to your sample.

Answer (score 0):

Use single-quotes in your XPath whenever possible to make your life easier :

```
nodeList = root.SelectNodes(@"/moviedb/movie[contains(genres, '"+ ElementValue +"')]");
```

Or you can use [`String.Format()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) method to concatenate values from variables into single string result in a more intuitive way (especially when you have many variables to be "injected" to the string) :

```
var xpath = String.Format("/moviedb/movie[contains(genres, '{0}')]", ElementValue);
nodeList = root.SelectNodes(xpath);
```